# Linear conflicts heuristic for 15 puzzle game

Tags: performance, algorithm, python-3.x, sliding-tile-puzzle, heuristic

I'm trying to solve the 15 Puzzle problem using IDA* algorithm with a Linear Conflicts heuristic. I already implemented the heuristic from what I understood : [link](https://medium.com/swlh/looking-into-k-puzzle-heuristics-6189318eaca2)

Here's my goal state ("snail" format) and initial state :

```
GOAL_STATE = 
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [12 13 14  5]
 [11  0 15  6]
 [10  9  8  7]]

INITIAL STATE = 
[[11  3  4  2]
 [14  8 12  9]
 [ 5  0 13  6]
 [ 7 15  1 10]]
```

I'm wondering how I can optimize my code (the `linear_conflict_heuristic()` function) which seems to be very redundant.

Also I'm not sure how I should be counting these slides (3, 4, 2) on the initial state. Does that count for 2, 3 or 4 conflicts ?

Here's my code so far :

```
import numpy as np


m = [[0] * 4 for i in range(4)]
dx, dy = [0, 1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1, 0]
x, y, c = 0, -1, 1
for i in range(4 + 4 - 2):
    for j in range((4 + 4 - i) // 2):
        x += dx[i % 4]
        y += dy[i % 4]
        m[x][y] = c
        c += 1


BOARD_LENGTH = 4
GOAL_STATE = np.array(m)


def goal_on_row(num, i):
    for j in range(BOARD_LENGTH):
        if num == GOAL_STATE[i][j]:
            return j


def goal_on_column(num, j):
    for i in range(BOARD_LENGTH):
        if num == GOAL_STATE[i][j]:
            return i

def linear_conflict_heuristic(state):
    result = 0
    for i in range(BOARD_LENGTH):
        for j in range(BOARD_LENGTH):
            num = state[i][j]
            if num != 0:
                position = goal_on_row(num, i)
                if position is not None:
                    if position <= j:
                        for k in reversed(range(j)):
                            num2 = state[i][k]
                            if num2 != 0:
                                position2 = goal_on_row(num2, i)
                                if position2 is not None:
                                    if position < position2:
                                        result += 1
                    else:
                        for k in range(j + 1, BOARD_LENGTH):
                            num2 = state[i][k]
                            if num2 != 0:
                                position2 = goal_on_row(num2, i)
                                if position2 is not None:
                                    if position > position2:
                                        result += 1

                position = goal_on_column(num, j)
                if position is not None:
                    if position <= i:
                        for k in reversed(range(i)):
                            num2 = state[k][j]
                            if num2 != 0:
                                position2 = goal_on_column(num2, j)
                                if position2 is not None:
                                    if position < position2:
                                        result += 1
                    else:
                        for k in range(i + 1, BOARD_LENGTH):
                            num2 = state[k][j]
                            if num2 != 0:
                                position2 = goal_on_column(num2, j)
                                if position2 is not None:
                                    if position > position2:
                                        result += 1
    
    return result


def main():
    state = np.array([[11, 3, 4, 2], [14, 8, 12, 9], [5, 0, 13, 6], [7, 15, 1, 10]])
    result = linear_conflict_heuristic(state)
    print(f"RESULT = {result}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```